# How to write and save csv files in a loop on google colab?

Tags: python, csv, save, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create and save multiple csv files (in a loop, 1 file per iteration) on a google colab notebook. I'm using

```
drive.mount('/drive')
f3.to_csv('/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/file.csv', index =False)
```

But obviously it's not working. the cell is giving me a text box to enter my authorization code.
Is there a way around this to save files in a loop?

To make it clear, here's the code

```
for k in portkey:
 f3 = f2[f2.port_key_anonymised == k]
 if f3.shape[0]>0 :
  drive.mount('/drive')
  f3.to_csv('/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/'+str(nb)+'.csv', index =False)
```

Thank you!

Comment: you don't have to mount it again and again. Just mount it once in a cell that is executed above before the loop

Comment: if you want to save in drive means you should give authorixation code.but if you want to save into colab means change the path to '/content'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mount the drive only once by providing the authorization code. After that, you have access to the file system and can read and write multiple files.

Your code should look something like this

```
# Mount drive
drive.mount('/drive')

# Save multiple CSV files
for k in portkey:
 f3 = f2[f2.port_key_anonymised == k]
 if f3.shape[0]>0 :
  # Save file
  f3.to_csv('/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/'+str(nb)+'.csv', index =False)
```